# SQL set UNIQUE only for two columns

Tags: sql, unique

I would like for example that user can add name JHONE and age 25, so next time he can add JHONE, 26  or ALEX 25, BUT not JHONE, 25 again.

So I'm looking for two column unique NOT separately.

P.S. I'm sorry if same question was mentioned before.

**EDIT:**

This is my example:

[image]

Would like to make userIdG and doWithCar will be like this

> 102163096246025413003  View
>
> 102163096246025413003  Buy
>
> 102163096246025413003  Let
>
> 102163096246025413003  Sell

And for Id = 102163096246025413003 you can't add any more values, BECAUSE column **doWithCar**  will have only 4 possible choice view, buy, rent and sell

Comment: First of all do not edit that way because you invalidate existing answers. Second it looks like `PhpMyAdmin` so it is rather **`MySQL`** not **`Microsoft SQL Server`** Third: It is a classic chamelon question. To sum up add `UNIQUE(userIdG, doWithCar)`.

Comment: @lad2025 Sorry if it was looks like chameleon question. I just try to understand the concept, but unfortunately I did not get it, that's why ask with existing issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could specify more than one column in `UNIQUE`:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(100), age INT
                ,UNIQUE(name, age));

INSERT INTO tab(name, age) VALUES ('John', 25);
INSERT INTO tab(name, age) VALUES ('John', 26);                 

-- INSERT INTO tab(name,age) VALUES ('John', 25);
-- Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__tab__CF0426FD76D3370A'. 
-- Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.tab'. 
-- The duplicate key value is (John, 25).
-- The statement has been terminated.

SELECT * FROM tab;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/UERRA48615)**</kbd>

Note:

You should store `date of birth` and not age itself (or make `age` calculated column and set `UNIQUE(name, dob)`).

---

> *this is what I do not understand) how database will know that it should be two columns as unique and not each column is unique*

These are different concepts. DB "knows" it from `UNIQUE` constraint definition:

```
UNIQUE(userIdG,doWithCar)              -- pair of column is unique
!=
UNIQUE(userIdG),UNIQUE(doWithCar)      -- each column is unique
```

Comment: I have updated my question, so I need to set userIdG and doWithCar as unique and (this is what I do not understand) how database will know that it should be two columns as unique and not each column is unique?

Comment: Update make sense now, ))) Now I should use ALTER TABLE userChioce ADD INDEX UQ_IDDO UNIQUE (userIdG, doWithCar) ???

Comment: CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_IDDO UNIQUE 
ON userChioce  (userIdG, doWithCar) or like this?

Comment: @J.FOG First you have to remove duplicates if exists any, second you should add `UNIUQE` constraint. If you need futher assistance consider asking new question with http://sqlfiddle.com demo with sample data.

Comment: I get it that I need to remove values, but about add INDEx is it like this?     
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UQ_IDDO UNIQUE ON userChioce (userIdG, doWithCar) ?

Comment: I would use something like: `ALTER TABLE userChoice ADD CONSTRAINT UQ_IDDO 
UNIQUE (userIdG, doWithCar)`